# Changing ID Chosen Being dropdown PHP

Tags: php

I have a script for the forum. By default, users can only post if it has opened the site to determine the parent first.
For example `domain.com/new.php?parent=3`

Here I am trying to modify using the dropdown.
For example:
OPTION 1 (value1)
OPTION 2 (value2)
OPTION 3 (value3)

I add `$parent=$_POST['parent'];` following the example of the `$title=$_POST['title'];` But always failed.

Is there a solution?

**CODE:**

```
<?php
//This page let users create new topics
include('config.php');
if(isset($_GET['parent']))
{
    $id = intval($_GET['parent']);
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $dn1 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(c.id) as nb1, c.name from categories as c where c.id="'.$id.'"'));
if($dn1['nb1']>0)
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="<?php echo $design; ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Style" />
        <title>New Topic - <?php echo htmlentities($dn1['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> - Forum</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href="<?php echo $url_home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $design; ?>/images/logo.png" alt="Forum" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
<?php
$nb_new_pm = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(*) as nb_new_pm from pm where ((user1="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and user1read="no") or (user2="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and user2read="no")) and id2="1"'));
$nb_new_pm = $nb_new_pm['nb_new_pm'];
?>
<div class="box">
    <div class="box_left">
        <a href="<?php echo $url_home; ?>">Forum Index</a> &gt; <a href="list_topics.php?parent=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($dn1['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a> &gt; New Topic
    </div>
    <div class="box_right">
        <a href="list_pm.php">Your messages(<?php echo $nb_new_pm; ?>)</a> - <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a> (<a href="login.php">Logout</a>)
    </div>
    <div class="clean"></div>
</div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['message'], $_POST['title']) and $_POST['message']!='' and $_POST['title']!='')
{
    include('bbcode_function.php');
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $title = stripslashes($title);
        $message = stripslashes($message);
    }
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
    $message = mysql_real_escape_string(bbcode_to_html($message));
    if(mysql_query('insert into topics (parent, id, id2, title, message, authorid, timestamp, timestamp2) select "'.$id.'", ifnull(max(id), 0)+1, "1", "'.$title.'", "'.$message.'", "'.$_SESSION['userid'].'", "'.time().'", "'.time().'" from topics'))
    {
    ?>
    <div class="message">The topic have successfully been created.<br />
    <a href="list_topics.php?parent=<?php echo $id; ?>">Go to the forum</a></div>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'An error occurred while creating the topic.';
    }
}
else
{
?>
<form action="new_topic.php?parent=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">
    <label for="title">Title</label><input type="text" name="title" id="title"  /><br />
    <label for="message">Message</label><br />
    <div class="message_buttons">
        <input type="button" value="Bold" onclick="javascript:insert('[b]', '[/b]', 'message');" /><!--
        --><input type="button" value="Italic" onclick="javascript:insert('[i]', '[/i]', 'message');" /><!--
        --><input type="button" value="Underlined" onclick="javascript:insert('[u]', '[/u]', 'message');" /><!--
        --><input type="button" value="Image" onclick="javascript:insert('[img]', '[/img]', 'message');" /><!--
        --><input type="button" value="Link" onclick="javascript:insert('[url]', '[/url]', 'message');" /><!--
        --><input type="button" value="Left" onclick="javascript:insert('[left]', '[/left]', 'message');" /><!--
        --><input type="button" value="Center" onclick="javascript:insert('[center]', '[/center]', 'message');" /><!--
        --><input type="button" value="Right" onclick="javascript:insert('[right]', '[/right]', 'message');" />
    </div>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="70" rows="6"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
        </div>
        <div class="foot"><a href="http://www.webestools.com/scripts_tutorials-code-source-26-simple-php-forum-script-php-forum-easy-simple-script-code-download-free-php-forum-mysql.html">Simple PHP Forum Script</a> - <a href="http://www.webestools.com/">Webestools</a></div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
}
else
{
    echo '<h2>The category you want to add a topic doesn\'t exist.</h2>';
}
}
else
{
?>
<h2>You must be logged to access this page.</h2>
<div class="box_login">
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
        <label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
        <label for="memorize">Remember</label><input type="checkbox" name="memorize" id="memorize" value="yes" />
        <div class="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" /> <input type="button" onclick="javascript:document.location='signup.php';" value="Sign Up" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
}
else
{
    echo '<h2>The ID of the category you want to add a topic is not defined.</h2>';
}
?>
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `input` element with the name `parent` in the 
form, therefore `$_POST['parent']` will not be set. Verify by dumping `$_POST` after submit: `var_dump($_POST)`.

You could reuse the `$id` variable which holds the `$_GET['parent']` value.

As it has been mentioned in the comments:

***Make sure to sanitize all input values before stating SQL queries to prevent SQL injection attacks!***